# mysql db not recognizing valid join

Tags: mysql, join, sqldatatypes

I'm not quite sure what the problem is here, I just know that the db isn't working properly.

Two show some basic data structure, table 1 looks like this

```
      name         | inGameID
Azure Plagioclase  |  17455
   Plagioclase     |  18
  viscous Pyroxeres|  17460
      Onyx Ochre   |  1232
```

table 2 resembles something like this

```
  userName  |    item
     sam    |   Onyx Ochre
    mike    |   viscous Pyroxeres
     dave   |    azure plagioclase
```

When attempting to run this query

```
SELECT fl.item, od.name 
FROM oreData od
JOIN fleetLog fl ON lower(od.name) = lower(fl.item)
order by fl.logID asc
```

The result is ONLY the onyx ochre value. When there should be far more data returned. Both t1.name and t2.item have the same data type. I'm not sure what more detail is needed to help diagnose this problem, but I'd love an extra set of eyes on this. I'm happy to give any further details. I do apologize for this being so vague, I've just never encountered an issue like this before

you guys hit the nail right on the head. it was extra white space either at the front or end of those values. What would be the best way to solve this?

```
'39';'2';'1';'2001-03-13 00:14:27';'userName';'322';'Vivid Hemorphite
'
'38';'2';'1';'2001-03-13 00:19:28';'userName';'6386';'Azure Plagioclase
'
```

Comment: Is there extra whitespace at the beginning or end of any values?  Can you try posting results of `select name,len(name) from oreData` and `select item,len(item) from fleetLog`?

Comment: Is there any superfluous whitespace in either record?  You might also consider dropping the `LOWER()` function calls and using a case-insensitive collation instead, e.g. `ON od.name = fl.item COLLATE utf8_general_ci`.

Comment: @eggyal i have tried both with and without and it is the same results.

Comment: @mellamokb i will run those and paste them into the top section

Comment: Have you tried `ON TRIM(od.name) = TRIM(fl.item)`

Comment: For instance, when I test with your data, it works fine and all three records match as expected: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bea61/2.

Comment: You guys were right on the money. extra white space. I will attempt trim to see if that fixes the issue!

Comment: is it turns out, more than white space, a character return existed at the end of it. discovered by exporting the db as a csv. so now to figure out why that is getting put in!

Comment: That's why it's usually better to have a meaningless primary key - an integer works nicely. You're less likely to have to re-visit all your foreign key relationships if you decide "Onyx Ochre" should be "Ochre Onyx", for starters. The "trim" and "lower" functions also mean you're probably not getting the benefit of any indexing on the tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> you guys hit the nail right on the head. it was extra white space either at the front or end of those values. What would be the best way to solve this?

1. Fix your application code so that such data does not enter the database; if this is not possible, you can define triggers within the database to strip characters as required during write operations:

   ```
   CREATE TRIGGER oreData_ins  BEFORE INSERT ON oreData  FOR EACH ROW
   SET NEW.name = TRIM(NEW.name);

   CREATE TRIGGER oreData_upd  BEFORE UPDATE ON oreData  FOR EACH ROW
   SET NEW.name = TRIM(NEW.name);

   CREATE TRIGGER fleetLog_ins BEFORE INSERT ON fleetLog FOR EACH ROW
   SET NEW.item = TRIM(NEW.item);

   CREATE TRIGGER fleetLog_upd BEFORE UPDATE ON fleetLog FOR EACH ROW
   SET NEW.item = TRIM(NEW.item);
   ```
2. Update the existing data:

   ```
   UPDATE oreData  SET name = TRIM(name);
   UPDATE fleetLog SET item = TRIM(item);
   ```

Comment: I'm using a regex to parse the data.
`$re = '/^(?<timeMined>[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}) # timeMined 
         \s+
         (?<userName>[\w\s]+)        # user name
         \s+(?:has\s+looted)\s+    # garbage text between name and amount
         (?<amount>\d+)              # amount
         \s+x\s+                     # multiplication symbol
         (?<item>.*)\s*$            # item name (to end of line)
       /xmu';`

Comment: @mhopkins321: Change `<item>.*` (which matches greedily) to `<item>.*?` (which matches lazily).  Note also that if the original string is XML (which is not a regular language), you can't correctly parse it with regular expressions: you should use an XML parser instead.